# Open Universal Link url in app and then same url in webview

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, deep-linking

I know how to implement Universanl Linking  and `UIWebView` stuffs. I have some urls which will open the application and want to load the same urls in the web view and there will be some process in web view and then will generate some links and on clicking that link on web view it should provide me token in the Application.

So how can i do following:

- Restrict user to go to app and stay in web view instead.
- Once the process of web view completes it should return token to the application.

Comment: Have you gone through this Webview Bridge ?
https://github.com/ShawnFoo/SwiftWebViewBridge

Comment: @itechnician I don't want to use any custom class in code. And that might not help me i think.